# Call Mono after first Mono is done and return result of first Mono

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to perform two business operations, in a Webflux environment, in a way that the second operation happens only after the first one is succesfull. After the second one is done, I want to return the result of the first operation. The second operation calls a org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient. This is what I have tried until now:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Resource>> callOperations(){
   return service.operation1()
          .flatMap(resource -> {
                   service.operation2();
                   return resource;
           })
          .map(ResponseEntity::ok);

}
```

I also tried with then and subscribe but I can't get the webclient to perform the call and return the result of service.operation1. What must I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct a flow using reactive operators and let WebFlux subscribe to it. In your snippet there is no subscription to `service.operation2()`

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Resource>> callOperations(){
   return service.operation1()
          .flatMap(resource -> {
                   return service.operation2()
                       .thenReturn(resource);
           })
          ...

}
```